# Cannot Use parameter for Selector in Swift Class

Tags: ios, swift, function

I don't actually get an error, but the buttons don't call the function when they get pressed. I created a class to make my buttons easier but there is an issue with the selector. Right now all this code is in my viewController at the moment.

```
class NavButton {
    var button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

    init(iconName: String, selector: Selector ){
        self.button.setImage(UIImage(named: iconName), for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
        self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        self.button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        self.button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        self.button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    }

    func construct() -> UIButton {
        return self.button
    }

}


private func setupNavBar(){

    let searchButton = NavButton(iconName:"search_icon", selector: #selector(handleSearch))
    let moreButton = NavButton(iconName:"nav_more_icon", selector: #selector(handleMore))
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchButton.construct())
    let moreBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: moreButton.construct())

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
        moreBarButtonItem,
        searchBarButtonItem
    ]
}

@objc func handleSearch(){
    print("search click")
}

@objc func handleMore(){
    print("more click")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selector`s only represent a method, but they don't represent on which object to call the method i.e. the *target*.

In your constructor, you set the target to `self`:

```
self.button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
                      ^^^^^
```

This means that the button, when pressed will try to call an instance method in the `NavButton` class. But you actually want to call the `handleSearch` method in some other class!

To fix this, add a target parameter in the constructor:

```
init(iconName: String, target: Any?, selector: Selector ){
    self.button.setImage(UIImage(named: iconName), for: UIControlState.normal)
    // note the change to the below line
    self.button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
    self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    self.button.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    self.button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    self.button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
}
```

And then call the constructor like this:

```
NavButton(iconName:"search_icon", target: self, selector: #selector(handleSearch))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the target as a parameter into the NavButton class.

```
init(iconName: String, target: Any?, selector: Selector){
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: iconName), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
    // Rest of method follows
}
```

The target should be the object on which the action selector is defined.